# Asking purely physics questions

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

It has not been many days since I joined this site. I thought of using this as to clarify my doubts while doing problems or increase my knowledge in physics. I put questions and ask just to give me hints on doing them and try my maximum to solve those before posting them here. But my questions always gets on hold because it is off-topic. I don't understand what is off-topic in my questions(except one on philosophical cosmology). All of them are pure applications of physics. Finally, when I put a question on relativity, going deep into physics so that it is not flagged off due to off-topic content there is no one to answer.

Comment: Because homework problems must abide by the homework policy. Have you tried seeing the link that is in the close reason for each of your closed questtions?

Comment: BTW folks, the mother meta is trying out a new voting ethic in which downvotes only mean disagreement on answers and on [feature-requestion] questions. On other question you vote for the *quality* of the question as with the main site. I think the point is to be less off-putting when new users come to meta.

Comment: @dmckee can you provide a link to the policy or discussions?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193884/a-proposal-for-more-constructive-downvoting-on-meta-express-disagreement-by-ans I'm still mulling over how I feel about this idea--it is nicer, but add complexity to how we understand things---and I don't feel we have to treat it as official here just yet, but I thought people should know.

Answer (score 6):

> I put questions and ask just to give me hints on doing them and try my maximum to solve those before posting them here.

I only see evidence of that in your latest question, and that was a "check my work" question.

In general, we only permit homework-like questions when they are asking for something conceptual.

---

In the case of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/75132/philosophical-cosmology-is-there-something-called-god), philosophy/"new" physics is off topic here because:

- This is *not* a discussion forum. We try to make a repository of useful questions and answers. Discussions are fun to participate in, but their content is generally not useful to others. We have [a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) for discussions.
- Even if "physicists are philosophers", physicists use more precise methods and have a different way of approaching the problem than the general philosopher. Metaphysics and philosophy is off topic here.
- The question wasn't a question in the first place.

---

Your relativity question is rather unclear. I think I've understood it (and may provide an answer if I get the time), but I doubt many have.

Comment: Every physics problem is also concept based. When I ask you about whether there is some mistake in my work I'm actually trying to rectify myself if I was conceptually wrong some where. Involving some numbers doesn't mean it is not conceptual.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR Basically, it should be something that's useful to others. Homework-y problems are not useful, they're too specific a problem. Others won't search for that, and it ends up helping only you. Sure, a concept will be involved, but you haven't focused on a specific concept here. See http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: In my questions I don't give the steps I did while solving it because I don't know to make it beautiful using the MathJax and without it the question would be more messier.

Comment: In the resistor one you're basically asking for heuristics, not physics. Mathjax/etc is irrelevant. The question is off topic by the homework policy.

Comment: So, I'm leaving this site. Good luck to everyone. But, before that I would like to know what would happen if the homework questions are off-topic and still you allow them and answer them?

Comment: I asked this to you because I'm also there in mathematics and chemistry stack exchange where there is no such problem. People clear my doubts and I too solve a lot of questions put by others.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR If they're off topic, how would we allow them? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: What does it mean by 'we'? Actually who runs this site?

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR (a) Each SE site has its own homework policy (b) I'm surprised you say that, while math is tolerant with homework, Chemistry follows the same policy. However most questions _from_ homework are directly conceptual and thus they are fine there.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR "we" = "the community". The site is run by Stack Exchange, however I am a community-elected moderator who helps enforce policies decided upon by the community. Like the homework policy.

Comment: What a rule man. You may think I'm selfish because I'm not able to get answers for my question but, there are many others who don't have qualified teachers nearby to clear their doubts. I thought this would be a nice platform. By, allowing homework questions(the one you consider as off-topic) this site would become a large resource of interesting questions which checks students conceptually as well as their problem solving ability. Many others would also benefit by solving other's tricky problems.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR If you wish to see the policy changed, bring it up in a new question tagged [tag:feature-request] (explain in detail why it is necessary).  There are plenty of other sites on the Internet that do homework help. _We don't cater to all needs of those doing physics_ , so it's irrelevant if people have a hard time getting their confusions cleared.

Comment: What does it mean by we don't cater? Every member of this site contributes towards solving other's problems and also posting questions. It is not that people will only accept the answers given by the community(i.e who moderates this site) for even the community to have a hard time.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR: Because this site is for *learning* physics, not for getting answers to your homework ffor marks.

Comment: If problem solving is not a part of studying physics then, why is it included in the curriculum in every school in the world. It is not just to get marks, it is how students learn to apply physics concepts in daily life. Problem solving is a great way to strengthen the concepts of a student. It is how students get to think of this beautiful universe(or rather multiverse)and this beautiful subject called physics.

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR: Guess what; it ' is irrelevant   ,. It may be somewhat useful to understand, but if you just say "Give me, the answer!", you're not learning or understanding  ***anything***                                       , ; you are just telling people  to solve your work for you. And you say "it's not just to get marks", then, (1) It doesn't help you understand if you simply, just    ask somoenej  to do the problem for you (2) so it's still about getting marks ? .  !

Comment: @RajathKrishnaR: Oh, and by the way, if you really have a good point for what you propose, as Manish Earth said,   make a proper meta post requwesting that. But I'm telling you;, it won't work;   simply                                                 because such questions are harmful to the site. P.S. I ' m pretty sure I had seen a comment-answer of yours on a no-work homework quezstion saying that it's not allowed... Why the sudden change of opinion ? . t